# VS2013 - Error on a view causes browser to display symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Using vs2013 to create an MVC5.2 web app. I'm actually rebuilding an old app using the new mvc framework, so this works fine in vs2010 and MVC3.

In this app, whenever i have something that would trigger an error on the page (usually in a razor syntax, like 
`@{Html.RenderPartial("mypartial", mymodel);}`

instead of getting a compilation error yellow screen when viewing it in a browser, i get a page of symbols:
[image: Compilation Error Symbols]

I created an new web app and it doesn't do it in there, it displays  the error as expected. I'm assuming this is caused by something i retrieved/updated via NuGet, but if anyone had any idea of where to start looking, it'd be appreciated.

EDIT: further experimenting seems to indicate that this only happens within areas. If i have a razor syntax error in the root controller, i get a yellowscreen. same error in a view that is in an area results in the symbol display below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem- I had added a EnableCompression action filter that i was using in MVC3 to my MVC5 controllers. This was causing the weird display- taking it out completely cleared up the problem.

Apparently now gzip compression is handled either in IIS or in the web.config file, I've seen reports of both. At any rate, I no longer have to deal with it in the application itself.